# Data extract error: User does not have access to the Extract ID

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have built a connector in java which pulls data from Exact Target using their Soap Api.
All of our Exact Target clients that are using this connector, have their ET account set up the same way (with the same user permissions), but for a few of them importing data extracts from Exact target fails with the following error:

**User does not have access to the Extract ID**

For these clients we need to contact the ET support team, give them the soap envelope for the request, and they will fix it. The problem is that this process is very time consuming and quite slow. Is there any setting that the ET user can set up himself in his account in order to avoid this error when doing a data extract request?

Thanks,
Erisa

Answer (score 1):

Your application can set User Permissions via the SOAP API:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/setting_user_permissions_via_the_web_services_api/